# Rails 3 - creating own model and working with an others

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, model, action

I have two tables for checking views (visits of the page) - views of pic (PhotoView) in gallery and photographers(PhotographerView).
Because these two models (and tables) are the same, I want to create a model for them - something like:

```
class Func < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.check_views(model_view, data)
    last_view = model_viewView.where('ip_address = ? AND request_url = ?', request.remote_ip, request.url).order('created_at DESC').first

    unless last_view
      model_view+View.new(...).save
      model_view.increment_counter(:views, data.id)

    else
      if (DateTime.now - last_view.created_at.to_datetime) > 1.day
        model_view+View.new(...).save
        model_view.increment_counter(:views, data.id)
      end
    end #comparing dates
  end
end
```

and call this method like:

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
Func.check_views('Photo', @photo)
```

When I try use it with the way above, I'll get the error **undefined method `check_views' for Func(Table doesn't exist):Class**

Could you give me a help, how to make it work?
Thank you

Comment: so `Func` doesn't have a table?

Comment: no, `Func` should be just like an auxiliary model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ActiveRecord::Concern` and modules to move the common functionality into one place as follows:

```
module CheckViews

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern


  module ClassMethods
    # all class methods go here, if you don't have any just leave it blank
  end

  def check_views(data)
    last_view = where('ip_address = ? AND request_url = ?', request.remote_ip, request.url).order('created_at DESC').first

    unless last_view
      @@views_class.new(...).save
      increment_counter(:views, data.id)

    else
      if (DateTime.now - last_view.created_at.to_datetime) > 1.day
        @@views_class.new(...).save
        increment_counter(:views, data.id)
      end
    end #comparing dates
  end

end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CheckViews

end
```

you can now do the following:

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
@photo.check_views
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very tempted to do this as a module extending the classes which want the Views functionality. Something like the following *ought* to work; but it's entirely untested and entirely unlike anything I've ever done before so it *may* be completely buggy. Fair warning.

```
module CheckViews

  def self.extended(host_class)
    host_class.class_variable_set("@@views_class", "#{host_class}View".constantize)
  end

  def check_views(data)
    last_view = where('ip_address = ? AND request_url = ?', request.remote_ip, request.url).order('created_at DESC').first

    unless last_view
      @@views_class.new(...).save
      increment_counter(:views, data.id)

    else
      if (DateTime.now - last_view.created_at.to_datetime) > 1.day
        @@views_class.new(...).save
        increment_counter(:views, data.id)
      end
    end #comparing dates
  end
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend CheckViews
  ...
end
```

(`extend` adds all the instance methods of the target `Module` as class methods of the calling class; so `Photo` gains `Photo.check_views(data)`, and `self` in that function is the class `Photo`.)